# How to create a subclass in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

During lecture, my professor very quickly created a subclass in Eclipse.

The result has the "extend" keyword added to the subclass. I didn't see what buttons he clicked.

Does anyone know where should I click? (I think he right clicked on the current class in the package explorer, then **New** ==> **class**, then I'm lost on what to select).

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't rely on the IDE to perform basic functions like this.  You should learn how to write the code for a sub-class yourself.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth While it's true that what you describe is more important, you assume that OP does not already know how to do this.  He might very well know but is specifically asking for help in using Eclipse.

Answer (score 16):

When you are viewing the class you want to subclass, open Type Hierarchy (press F4). Right click on the parent-to-be class, and in the menu go to new -> class ( or Ctrl-n , class ).

Comment: Thanks, this answer should be accepted. I haven't found any easier/faster way to do subclassing yet.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Type your super class name where highlighted]

Please see the picture where to enter your existing super class

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project name on `Package Explorer` + Add `New` Class + Type `package` Name, `Name` (sub-class name), and `Super class` (or Click on Browse to choose super class).

Comment: still can't get it to work, can you be a bit more specific on what to click? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind Keys for New (New Wizard: Class) command (for eg.: Ctrl + Alt + N) by open Window> Preferences > General > Keys.

And then, on new wizard window, change the Superclass box.

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

Rt click on class > Show in Package Explorer 
Ctrl-N > Class
The selected class will be automatically populated as the super class and you can enter you class name to derive from that

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class, replace the name of superclass with the your superclass name, that will do the job.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.