# Best way to subclass in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to generate a subclass real fast and wonder which is the quickest / best way? There seems to be no option to e.g. right-click and "Generate subclass.." but that could be a reasonable code development option since that would save me writing manually what extends what.

Do you have any opinion or facts about this feature, should it exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508498/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-eclipse-java-ee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Refactor -> Extract Superclass... is pretty close. Make your existing class the subclass and make create the superclass. Then rename as you wish after that. Not sure why there is no Extract Subclass..., but I imagine they have thought about that and for some reason did not find it necessary.