# How can I create a subclass of an abstract class automatically in Eclipse in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, abstract-class

say I had an abstract java class in eclipse. Now I want to create some subclasses of that abstract class. Is there a way to create them automatically where I just enter the name of the class and eclipse creates the necessary methods?

I thought that I would find it in the "Refactor" option but I didn't. Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a subclass in Eclipse Java EE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508498/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-eclipse-java-ee)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, create a new class using **Right Click** (on the package where you want to create the class) > **New** > **Class**, and in the **SuperClass** field, you can select your `abstract` class. Be sure that the checkbox **Which method stubs would you like to** > **Inherited abstract methods** is checked.

[image: Create a subclass of an abstract class]

If you have already created your class, you can make it extend you `abstract` class by hand, and use **Right Click** (on the source code) > **Source** > **Override/Implement Methods...** and choose which methods you want to implement (if they are not already implemented).

[image: Override/Implment Methods...]

An other way to do it, is to extend your `abstract` class by hand, and use the **Quick Fix** provided by *Eclipse* to **Add unimplemented methods**. You can call the **Quick Fix** tooltip by highlighting the error and using **Ctrl+1**, or by clicking on the error icon on the left of the code.

[image: Quick Fix]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `New Class` as normal but then specify your abstract class as the `Superclass`. Then check `Which methods stubs would you like to create` -> `inherited abstract methods`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class extending the abstract class, by default eclipse will add all unimplemented methods